# self-join query on global catalog

Tags: active-directory

I need to retrieve information about an employee (strUser variable stores their sAMAccountName )ID and their manager by querying the global catalog, using classic ASP. This works:

```
'=========Account and connection string information for LDAP=======
Set objDomain = GetObject ("GC://RootDSE")
objADsPath = objDomain.Get("defaultNamingContext")
Set objDomain = Nothing
Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConn.provider ="ADsDSOObject"
objConn.Properties("User ID") = "..." 'domain account with read access to LDAP
objConn.Properties("Password") =  "..." 'domain account password
objConn.Properties("Encrypt Password") = True
objConn.open "Active Directory Provider"
Set objCom = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set objCom.ActiveConnection = objConn
objCom.CommandText ="select name, givenName, sn, distinguishedName, manager, telephonenumber, mobile, mail, company, title, department, sAMAccountName,userAccountControl, msexchhidefromaddresslists FROM 'GC://"+objADsPath+"'  where sAMAccountname='"+strUser+"'"

'=======Executre query on LDAP for all accounts=========
Set objRS = objCom.Execute
```

Now if I'm trying to use an alias for GC e.g.:
    FROM 'GC://"+objADsPath+"' AS e
I get into an infinite loop.

What I need is a way to self-join query on global catalog (as e for employee, and m for manager) where e.manager = m.distinguishedName, in other words the relationship for the self-join in that the employee's manager is the manager's distinguished name.

How to do this?

I would also appreciate any hint to documentation.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that works is to embed a second query for manager details within the outer query for employee details.

```
objCom2.CommandText ="select sAMAccountName, name, givenName, sn, distinguishedName, manager FROM 'GC://"+objADsPath+"' where distinguishedName='" + manager + "'"
```

I would still like to know if GC self-join query is possible or not.